# Determine whether there is a subset of size n which has a standard deviation <= s

Tags: time-complexity, subset, standard-deviation

Given a bunch of numbers, I am trying to determine whether there is a "clump" anywhere where numbers are very densely packed.

To make things more precise, I thought I'd ask a more specific problem: given a set of numbers, I would like to determine whether there is a subset of size `n` which has a standard deviation <= `s`. If there are many such subsets, I'd like to find the subset with the lowest standard deviation.

So question #1 : does this formal problem definition effectively capture the intuitive concept of a "clump" of densely packed numbers?

- EDIT: I don't actually care about determining which numbers belong to this "clump", I'm much more interested in determining where the clump is centred, which is why I think that specifying `n` in advance is okay. But feel free to correct me!

And question #2 : assuming it does, what is the best way to go about implementing something like this (in particular, I want a solution with lowest time complexity)? So far I think I have a solution that runs in `n log n`:

- First, note that the lowest-standard-deviation-possessing subset of a given size must consist of consecutive numbers. So step 1 is sort the numbers (this is `n log n`)
- Second, take the first `n` numbers and compute their standard deviation. If our array of numbers is 0-based, then the first `n` numbers are `[0, n-1]`. To get standard deviation, compute `s1` and `s2` as follows:

  - `s1 = sum of numbers`
  - `s2 = sum of squares of numbers`

  Then, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Rapid_calculation_methods) says that the standard deviation is `sqrt(n*s2 - s1^2)/n`. Record this value as the highest standard deviation seen so far.
- Find the standard deviation of `[1, n]`, `[2, n+1]`, `[3, n+2]` ... until you hit the the last `n` numbers. To do each computation takes only constant time if you keep track of `s1` and `s2` running totals: for example, to get std dev of `[1, n]`, just subtract the 0th element from the `s1` and `s2` totals and add the nth element, then recalculate standard deviation. This means that the entire standard deviation calculating portion of the algorithm takes linear time.

So total time complexity `n log n`.

Is my assessment right? Is there a better way to do this? I really need this to run *fast* on fairly large sets, so the faster the better! Space is less of an issue (I *think*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having been working recently on a similar problem, both the definition of the clumps and the proposed implementation seem reasonable.

Another reasonable definition would be to find the minimum of all the ranges of `n` numbers. Thus, given that the list of numbers `x` is sorted, one would just find the minimum of `x[n]-x[1]`, `x[n+1]-x[2]`, etc. This would be slightly quicker than finding the standard deviation because it would avoid the multiplications and square roots. Indeed, you can avoid the square roots even when looking for the lowest standard deviation by finding the minimum variance (the square of the standard deviation), rather than the sd itself.

A caution would be that the location of the biggest clump might be quite sensitive to the choice of `n`. If there is an *a priori* reason to select a particular `n`, that won't be a problem. If not, however, it might require some experimentation to select the value of `n` that fairly reliably finds the clumps you are looking for, whether you are selecting by range or by standard deviation. Some ideas on this can be found in Chapter 6 of the online book [ABC of EDA](http://dspace.library.cornell.edu%2Fbitstream%2F1813%2F78%2F2%2FA-B-C_of_EDA_040127.pdf&ei=0qTHUYzeEIW0kQXWooGYAQ&usg=AFQjCNGqSqRK3yPyAkZiquhaTP89P6LpSg&bvm=bv.48293060,d.dGI).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think I will use your suggestion of minimum range instead of minimum std dev. Not only is it easier to calculate, but I find it much easier to reason about. I can choose a reasonable range because I can imagine what a clump of n points squeezed into a certain range looks like. It's much more difficult for standard deviation.